# How to remove all the prefix digits in a String value?

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove all the preceding/prefix digits from a String.

**Input:**

```
2025715-01 -2025715-Test_482080  
2025715-02 -2025715-Test1 (2015-7-9 19_11_3)  
2025715-03 -2025715-Test2_482080 - signed  
2025715-04 -2025715-Test3  
2025715-11 -2025715-Test4, PTO  
2025715-13 -2025715-Test5  
2025734-01 -2025734-Test6_402772
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Test_482080    
Test1 (2015-7-9 19_11_3)  
Test2_482080 - signed  
Test3  
Test4, PTO  
Test5  
Test6_402772
```

Note: The input prefix can vary in length. It's not a fixed length as shown above.

Have tried the below regex patterns so far, but its not working.

```
String str = string.replaceFirst("^[0-9]", "");  
String str = string.replaceFirst("^(\\d+.*|-\\d+.*)","");  
String str = string.replaceFirst("\\d","");
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why not just `substring`?  The prefix appears to have the same length every time.  Also please posted what have you attempted, this is not a code writing service.

Comment: Your examples remove more than digits.

Comment: Have tried String str = string.replaceFirst("^[0-9]", "");
String str = string.replaceFirst("^(\\d+.*|-\\d+.*)","");
String str = string.replaceFirst("\\d",""); But nothing seems to be working so far

Comment: @Nexevis The prefix is not of the fixed length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all spaces, hyphens and digits from the beginning of the string, as your examples suggest, this regular expression should do the trick:

```
^[- 0-9]*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vAQuCL/1)